# React Axios and Fetch POST method not working with C# WebAPI token request

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, fetch, axios

I am struggling to get a C# WebAPI auth token using react. I have a Postman request that works correctly; it gives me my token as expected:

[image]

I have tried recreating this request using both Axios and Fetch. The requests were as follows:

```
Attempt 1:
fetch('http://localhost:56765/token', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ username: 'test@test.com', password: 'Test123!', grant_type: 'password' })
})

Attempt 2:
axios('http://localhost:56765/token', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({ username: 'test@test.com', password: 'Test123!', grant_type: 'password' })
})

Attempt 3:
const data = JSON.stringify({ username: 'test@test.com', password: 'Test123!', grant_type: 'password' });
const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', };
axios.post('http://localhost:56765/token', data, { headers })
```

When I make the request, the response is:

```
400 Bad Request
{"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}
```

Picture example:
[image]

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Edit:

The code that worked for me was installing `qs` then:

```
var qs = require('qs');

const data = qs.stringify({ username: 'test@test.com', password: 'Test123!', grant_type: 'password' });
axios.post('http://localhost:56765/token', data)
```

I was able to completely omit the header.

Many thanks to Brub for answering on Xmas day!

Comment: Have you tried debugging this on the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing content-type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded but the actual form data of type application/json.  You want to post the data as form-urlencoded described here:

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/350#issuecomment-227270046

Note the Oauth 2.0 spec requires application/x-www-form-urlencoded

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.2